# backward compatibility using HTML5 tags

Tags: html, cross-browser

1. I Want my CSS to work properly even for old browsers that does uses HTML5 tags.
2. I have used  tag and defined a style associated with it, this style works perfect for new browser but doesn't work for old browser (text in  tag is rendered as normal text)
3. Here is the code:

---

```
    <style>
    .nav {
      color: red
      }
    nav {
      display: block;
      background-color: blue
      }
    </style>
    <div>
     <nav class="nav">
      <p>this is nav text</p>
     </nav>
```

**This code does not work for old browsers.**
How to solve this problem so as all tags used by me should render properly in all browsers.

Comment: and what is your code?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert minified distribution shiv in head element' (after or before your CSS):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="[PATH]/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/
https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv
History behind it: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/