# Internet Explorer redirect on all .Net Core project pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm a .Net Core beginner and look for a solution to protect the application from IE.

I got the following code working in Controller:

```
string userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
var flagsIE = new [] {"MSIE", "Trident"};

if(flagsIE.Any(userAgent.Contains)){
    return RedirectToAction("BadBrowser");
}
```

Now if someone is trying to visit the page using IE, they get redirected to an info-page asking them to use a modern browser. Instead of adding this code to every single Controller.cs I would like to add it on project level, so that it get's executed independent from the location within of the project.

And, I know that this can be achieved with _Layout.cshtml, my question is:
Where and how would I implement a function to get it executed for all requested views withing the project without adding it every single request within Controller.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you could look into some [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). That said, I get that you don't want to support IE anymore and that might be fair, but why not just do it on client side instead (by using feature detection vs user agent string)?

Comment: I have been using feature detection in the past. But the requirement of this particular project are set on a project level back-end solution. So I defaulted to the user-agent since that's all I got and because of the controlled environment of the end-clients is relative reliable.

Comment: @Icepickle if you make your response an answer, you'll get the right answer.

Comment: Seeker, since you self answered, just add an answer and mark it as such, I didn't really have the time to look into that :) No need to change the title or edit your question, self answering questions is entirely valid (you even get a badge for it :) )

Comment: @Icepickle I'm aware. But I was only able to solve it because of your comment. So I wanted to give you the badge. Oh well...

Comment: No worries, if I would have time for giving an answer and investigating if it worked, I would have done so, I only gave you a link and you did the rest :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Icepickle suggested, in the comments of my question, I used middleware in `Startup.cs` and got the desired result:

```
        app.Use(async (context,next) =>
            {
                string userAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
                var IEkeywords = new [] {"MSIE", "Trident"};

                if (IEkeywords.Any(userAgent.Contains)){
                    context.Response.Redirect("/IE/redirect/badbrowser.html");
                    return;
                }

                await next();
            });
```

Comment: If you don't redirect to a static html file but to a mvc route, you would have to check if the requested url is not the one you are redirecting to, or you could end up in a loop.
Something like 
`if (IEkeywords.Any(userAgent.Contains) && !context.Request.GetDisplayUrl().Contains("browser-not-supported"))`

Comment: That is precisely why I created a minimalistic static page informing users about their questionable browser choice. But I definitely can see the benefit of your code in some other cases.

Comment: Be sure to add this after `app.UseStaticFiles()`

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add js in _Layout.cshtml to detect the browser is IE:

```
 <script>
        var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
        if (isIE) {
            window.location.href = "/Home/ForbidInfo";
        }

    </script>
```

Then create a view named `ForbidInfo` under Home controller which to show the message to user that he cannot use the IE to show views.

(Notes: this view's Layout must be **null** ,or it will enter an endless loop)

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ForbidInfo";
    Layout = null;
}

<h1>Please use a modern browser!</h1>
```

After these settings, when you running a view in IE, it will be redirected to the FordidInfo page.

If your page does not use _layout, then you need to add the js on the corresponding view separately to ensure that it will not be displayed in IE.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm aware of that. And other ways doing it client side... the requirement is asking for back-end. I wish it wouldn't but that's what it is.

Comment: @TheSeeker Put that feature check with a redirect at the start of every page. If it is passed, load the actuall page. If it fails, show the error message. It is just one of those things that has to be in every last page, same as a .css file.

Comment: @Christopher in my experience, you always have users who don't read similar warnings and errors so I fully understand the need to disable the browser as a whole. Our users too must have IE installed, because of few applications but for new applications we dont support IE. So I fully understand what TheSeeker is seeking for.

Answer (score 1):

Never do that. Excluding browsers with redirects, is what lead to massive user agent spoofing. Effectively making that AgentId useless. And the way you wrote it, you may get a lot of false-positives.

It is also a bad idea from the early days of the internet, we are hoping to get rid off:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing

Comment: TY for your reply. But I'm not worried about that, since this application is running within of an internal network not facing the internet users.

I'm not new to web development. Only to .Net.

Comment: But... just of curiosity. How else would you assure that you can code using the modern web standards (HTML5/CSS3/ES6) without having a total blowout every time an IE user tries to use the web app?

Comment: @TheSeeker If you got a highly managed Environment, it is just a mater of telling their IT department. It is the IT deparments job to make sure the users do not use unsecure, out of date browsers like IE. | However, it looks like HTML 5 as designed with supporting older browsers in mind: https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/learn-html5-in-5-minutes-backwards-compatibility-for-older-browsers.html | https://stackoverflow.com/a/22267631/3346583 | Supporting older browsers might already be solved.

Comment: I had this discussion with the IT about IE. Which has to stay available to a number of users that work with legacy web application that will be removed in the next few years. MS stopped development on IE11 half way through implementing HTML5 because at that point they introduced Edge. But if you really interested about the IE support for HTML5, here you go: https://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-11/chrome-68/firefox-60.html

Comment: @TheSeeker According to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent, Edge identifies as: **"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18363"**. While IE 11 on Windows 10 identifies as **"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"** I would guess "WOW64" is the part that actually idetifies it as IE 11 or generally a pre-edge Windows Browser.

Comment: OK. If your really want to know here it is... No, [`WOW64`](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_system_name/windows/) doesn't identify IE, but `Trident` does. Trident is MS' rendering engine for IE. I check MSIE for potential legacy browsers, Trident is the actual identifier for IE11.